# Updating Excel columns(or rows?) based on a condition

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel file with usernames, city. I am trying to add a new column to the same excel, lets say the column is Dept. I have differemnt list of users which tells me which user belong to which dept. I am now trying to update the Dept column in the original excel file I have. My current code as follows

```
$test = import-csv .\test.csv | Select Name,City,Dept
if ($test.name = 'John'){
$test.Dept = 'HR' 
}
```

It doesnt work, getting this error

```
Exception setting "Name": "The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:2 char:1
+ $test.Name= 'John'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Not sure where I am doing wrong and if this is even correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out here, use *dept* or any other column name, which you want to add instead of *column3*.

```
Import-Csv file.csv | 
Select-Object *,"column3" | 
Export-Csv file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Not sure how it helps me in this context. I need to write in Dept column depending on condition based on Name.